# Amazon Certificate Manager .edu domain support

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl-certificate, verification

I requested a certificate for a subdomain similar to xxx.xxx.domain.edu but I get a message saying "The status of this certificate request is "Failed". Additional verification required to request certificates for one or more domain names in this request. Learn more.". Clicking Learn More does not provide any useful info.

Could this have something to do with the .edu domain? I have requested many certificated for .com domains without a problem.

Answer (score 1):

Certain domain names (or suffixes) appear to be flagged for additional verification beyond the standard process.

> **Additional Verification Required**
>
> ACM requires additional information to process this certificate request. To provide this information, use the [Support Center](https://console.aws.amazon.com/support/home) to contact AWS Support. If you don't have a support plan, post a new thread in the [AWS Certificate Manager discussion forum](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/forum.jspa?forumID=206).
>
> http://docs.aws.amazon.com/acm/latest/userguide/troubleshooting.html#failed-additional-verification-required

Although unrelated to the current question regarding `.edu`, the documentation also points out that requesting a cert for an Amazon-owned domain name ending with values like `amazonaws.com`, `cloudfront.net`, or `elasticbeanstalk.com` will also trigger this status, since you can't request a cert for those domains.  This implies that there's a domains suffix greylist behind the scenes that triggers the requirement for additional verification, presumably for security purposes.